# Ajax is not working if add form tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dragable point on line which change input value and self value. I need to create form to pass data by post. Everything is working well, but when i add form tag, ajax stop working(values does not change). Writing that "**Uncaught TypeError: tarif is not a function**" How can i solve it?
Here is my code:

```js
function tarif() {
  const nov = $('#new').val();
  const team = $('#team').val();
  const company = $('#company').val();
  const umn = $('#range').val();
  var sum = 0;
  if (+nov == 7000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += 7000;
  }
  if (+team == 13000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += 13000;
  }
  if (+company == 19000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += 19000;
  }
  if (+$('input[name=tarif]:checked').val() == 7000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum = 7000 + 1000 * +umn;
  }
  if (+$('input[name=tarif]:checked').val() == 13000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum = 13000 + 1500 * +umn;
  }
  if (+$('input[name=tarif]:checked').val() == 19000) {
    var sum = 0;
    sum = 19000 + 2000 * +umn;
  }
  $('#sizevalue').text('x' + umn);
  $('#price-tarif').val(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="tariff">
  <div class="container">

    <h2>Choose your plan</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>Plan</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span class="no-margin">
       <input type="radio" name="tarif" onchange="tarif()" value="7000" id="new" checked>
       <label for="new">New</label>
      </span>
        <span>
       <input type="radio" name="tarif" onchange="tarif()" value="13000" id="team">
       <label for="team">Team</label>
      </span>
        <span>
       <input type="radio" name="tarif" onchange="tarif()" value="19000" id="company">
       <label for="company">Company</label>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="row slider2-1 m25">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label style="padding-top: 25px;">Сoefficient</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="sizevalue">x0</div>
          <input id="range" onchange="tarif()" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" name="umn" list="tickmarks">
          <datalist id="tickmarks">
       <option value="0" label="x0">
       <option value="1" label="x1">
       <option value="2" label="x2">
       <option value="3" label="x3">
       <option value="4" label="x4">
       <option value="5" label="x5">
      </datalist>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row slider2">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label class="row" style="padding-left:11px">Login</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="login">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row slider2">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="phone">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row slider2-1 m2">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label>Total sum</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" value="7000" name="price" id="price-tarif">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: function tarif() should be outside document.ready

Comment: I have same, i had function inside` $(document).ready(function(){});` and i closed it totally. Should i insert function inside it maybe? I will try now

Comment: @RohitasBehera tried, also not working)) Tarif function is outside of document.ready

Comment: @DelightedD0D run my code and look to the Plan`s radio buttons, on click to them it changes value of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Ajax not working"

Almost certainly, now that you've added a `form` tag, you are now submitting the html form itself before the ajax code gets called, which is the default behaviour of your `<button type="submit">Confirm</button>` when inside a `form` tag.

If you want to submit via ajax, change your button to use `type="button"`

### JS error

In general, dont use inline javascript (the onchange attribute). Instead, use event handlers. To do this moddify your html like:

```
<input id="range" class="tarif" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" name="umn" list="tickmarks">
```

Then add an event handler like this:

```
$('.tarif').change(function(){
    tarif();
});
```

#### [Here is a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/75/)

Also, your html is missing the closing `</form>` tag.